# If the solution was a simple upgrade, should I close or answer my question?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23920/wifi-simply-wont-turn-on) was eventually resolved simply by getting the latest updates.

Since the problem was simply a matter of a buggy ROM that is now in the past, is it worth answering, or would it be better to close the question?

I have a few like this, and I want to keep both the site and my profile clean of extraneous posts, so please advise.

Answer (score 14):

Answer it, it is almost certain that you're not the only person experiencing the issue, and other people might have the same problem that will be helped by knowing that the issue is fixed in the newer version, that will convince them to update or at least they may be able to find a workaround after knowing the nature of the problem. Make sure to include the version info of the buggy software and the version that fixed the problem.

Comment: Agree, I've had a couple of problems I've posted here that were later sorted out by an upgraded/patched version of the OS/app, in those cases I've answered with which version fixed it and then accepted my answer.